# What answer characteristics are the most important when accepting an answer to a question?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

When choosing between answers to a question, which aspects of the answer are the most important when accepting an answer? This could include things such as:

- Length
- Inclusion of code snippets or samples
- Are alternate answers ignored when an accepted answer is present?
- Reputation of the poster
- Other factors?

Comment: How about "does the answer work" or "did the answer help me"?

Comment: None of the listied things should have any bearing on choosing the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

One factor:

- It is the answer that helped you most. Period.